# Posting OpenLayers VectorTiles on GeoServer

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geoserver

I am slowly losing my head in this problem.
Context: I'm fairly new to webserver, javascript etc. so my knowledge is very limited.

It seems very simple: I want to draw Features on a Website using **OpenLayers** and safe them for later use on a GeoServer.

I've tried mainly posting GeoJSON using the official Importer Extension for the **GeoServer**, but I was stuck because it does not support **GeoJSON**, however **GeoJSON** seems to be the go to format according to **OpenLayers** **Doc**.
Most importantly I want to avoid using these huge **Shapefiles**, which are very unhandy and unreadable.

Now I'm getting a huge overhead, because it seems like there is a simple and basic solution everyone uses, but me.

If you need any code examples of what I've done feel free, but I feel like they are not neccesary for my question.

Maybe one last thing: I am developing a prototyp for my company so it would be even better if there is a solution where I can "capsule" the website from the backend using the GeoServer *REST-API* for example.

Thanks in advance.